# Hide console application from taskbar

Tags: windows, vb.net, console, taskbar

so so far I've gotten my console application to minimize itself, but I want it to be totally hidden: so I want to disable it from showing in the taskbar too. With a Windows form this was easy, but I'm not so sure about console apps.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just change the Application Type in Project + Properties to Winforms.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, you want to hide the console used to launch the application? That is a separate application.

Otherwise look at ProcessStartInfo

Comment: Search for ProcessStartInfo here in Stackoverflow. Or check the duplicate questions on the right ------->

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new Window Application and start a process on load.
Make sure the main window is invisible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that, but is there any other way to do it inside the console application itself?

Comment: As far as I know not, but probably there will be SOME way. I always used this because I couldn't find something else, after VB.net I went to C# where you can create a window application and just write the console code in the Program.cs

Answer (score -1):

Right click on your project name in solution explorer and then go to properties and change the output type to Windows Application and then save it.
If you want to stop the app you should go to task manager and then go to services tab and search your app then stop it.

(If your project is a console application)